# Something strange with memcpy function

Tags: c, function, memcpy

I found a code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { 
    char buffer[20];
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        memcpy(buffer+i, "H", 1);
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is why there is : buffer + i and what does 1 mean at the end? Can anyone explain me

Comment: Princess does not google herself? http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.2.1

Comment: The code overwrites the end of your buffer, so the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Is it okay now Eric J.?

Comment: @EricJ. Where does it do so?

Comment: It's been edited.  The for loop used to run into the 50's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `buffer + i` is a pointer to a memory location at an offset of `i` chars from `buffer`. It is equivalent to `&buffer[i]`.
2. The `1` at the end means copy 1 byte.
3. Keep in mind that since you copy 1 byte only you are not copying the null terminating character of `"H"`.

Comment: But I dont't understand because the variable i is an int variable

Comment: The concept is called pointer arithmetic. `i` is (cast to) a non-negative integer and is multiplied with the size of a `buffer` element, 1 byte in this case.

Comment: Yeah but to stock a letter in a variable, `i` should be declared as `int`, right?

Comment: `i` is the number of chars. Imagine that buffer is a row of cars starting from zero. buffer + 2 would point to the 3rd car. If buffer was a row of bicycles buffer + 2 would point to the 3rd bicycle. The larger the elements in the buffer the larger the distance from the start.